Antd how to force view to be responsive
I have a view like this

on mobile view this changes to this:

but I want to use the same component in a desktop view and render the component in mobile view, I have tried setting the width but it does not trigger the view changes. what is the right way I can render the same component in mobile view but on desktop browser itself.
